# python3.5 + MySQLdb: 'charset' is an invalid keyword argument

Tags: python, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm using [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) with python3.6.

As the link above said, this is how I do:

```
import _mysql

try:
            db = _mysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='password', db='mydb', charset='utf8')
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
```

However, I get an error:

> 'charset' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

If I remove `charset='utf8'`, everything will be fine. But I need `utf8` because there are some special characters in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `_mysql`?  Perhaps you meant `MySQLdb`?  Perhaps `use_unicode=True` is also required?

More Python notes: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python